# T4 timeout on modem according to the logs

Tags: networking

I am confused about the statistics provided by the modem.

[image]

According to it, the signal is strong and clear, but by the upstream I have only partial service. According to the network log, I got a bunch of T4 timeout, but according to the upstream statistics there weren't any T4 timeouts. In my experience the internet is okay, there is no packet loss, lag, modem restart, etc... So what is wrong with my network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a faulty crimped F connector on a coax cable.

[image]

I replaced it with a cable having a compressed F connector. Now I have 5 upstream channels instead of 2 and everything works fine. :-)

[image]